# integrating wmd editor with a django site

Tags: django, macos, shell, django-admin

this is probably a really dumb question but im struggling to integrate it. im playing with a reusable app called brookie that uses wmd-editor.

in the install instructions it states to "Link admin_wmdeditor/media/admin-wmdeditor in your MEDIA_ROOT as admin-wmdeditor"

im assuming this is a symlink?

I've tried to create a symlink to point at the wmd folder in lib/python2.6/site-packages/wmd but i don't think it worked. i say that, as i cant see any symlink created in my folder.

so 1st question, is there a simple way to list symlinks so i can see if i've really created one? i know this is a noob question, im not a mac genius. i also know this should be covered by a quick google but do me a favour and do it, i can only find noise.

if anyone has some slightly more explicit instructions other than the ones on django-adminwmd_editors github page i'd love to see them. i can normally work this stuff out, but i've got an hour in just trying to hook this stuff up and its a wind up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac crack, but usually (on Linux) you can see a symlink, when you list the directory content.

I've played around with the brookie app some time ago and if I remember it right I have had some trouble with wmd also, after researching stackoverflow I changed to Markitup, which works fine.

Have a look here: [WMD in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258138/wmd-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

in the end i just commented out the lines referring to wmd and removed the class reference to it, forced it back to a std modeladmin.

will be adding tiny mce in if it needs it, nice n simple. not sure why this single text box needed something as complicated as wmdeditor.